# IOS Media player on Xamarin with native media controls

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

This is a very simple function that's return a view containing a video inside.

Works fine, but I'd like to add the native iOS media controls like play, pause, progress on the bottom, full screen button of the video just like the image bellow. Any suggestions ?

```
private UIView createVideo(Page p, int ndx)
{
    UIView v = new UIView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(p.elements[ndx].left * app.scale, p.elements[ndx].top * app.scale, p.elements[ndx].width * app.scale, p.elements[ndx].height * app.scale)); 
    AVPlayer _player;
    AVPlayerLayer _playerLayer;
    AVAsset _asset;
    AVPlayerItem _playerItem;
    _asset = AVAsset.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromFilename("videos/" + p.elements[ndx].file));
    _playerItem = new AVPlayerItem(_asset);
    _player = new AVPlayer(_playerItem);
    _playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer.FromPlayer(_player);
    _playerLayer.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, p.elements[ndx].width * app.scale, p.elements[ndx].height * app.scale);
    v.Layer.AddSublayer(_playerLayer);
    return v;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you looked a `AVPlayerViewController`, it provides all the controls for  `AVPlayer` content : https://developer.apple.com/reference/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller

Comment: HUmmm...I did't know...thanx, buddy ! I just got this media player from Xamarin Web site and I though it's was the ios native player

Comment: `AVPlayerViewController` is a complete UI for displaying `AVPlayer` content: review the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39138332/4984832